# RxSwift: how to have one observable trigger another one?

Tags: rx-swift

Suppose I have observable `A`, and I am trying to create observable `B` that emits two events: the first when `A` emits an event, and the second 5 seconds later.

So far I have the following:

```
self.B = Observable.create { [unowned self] observer in
            self.A.subscribe(onNext: {
                observer.onNext(0)
                self.delay(5) {
                    observer.onNext(1)
                }
            })
            return Disposables.create()
        }
```

This works, but I feel uncomforatble subscribing to `A` from a closure. Is there a nicer way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to reuse the `a` observable for the delayed observable. Below is the code to do it, along with a proof of concept.

```
let a = button.rx.tap.asObservable()
let delay = a.delay(5.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
let b = Observable.of(a, delay).merge()

b.subscribe(onNext: {
    print("foo")
}).disposed(by: bag)
```

Comment: I'm using a hot observable for `a` in the above. If your `a` is a cold observable, you will need to `share()` or `publish()` it.

Comment: amazing answer as usual +1